# Writing data to firebase data base , for location and time stamp

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geolocation

I am trying to write data to firebase in a certain format. Currently I have hard coded the location and time. I have my react native scripts for firebase , below .
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

```
import 'firebase/auth';
import firebaseConfig from './firebaseConfig';
// Initialize Firebase App
if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}
export const auth = firebase.auth();
export const loginWithEmail = (email, password) =>
  auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
export const registerWithEmail = (email, password) =>
  auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
export const logout = () => auth.signOut();
export const passwordReset = email => auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email);
```

And i am using two methods to write to the firebase database

```
let test1 = firebase.database().ref('Node/').push(auth.currentUser.email);
let test2 = firebase.database().ref('Node/').push(auth.currentUser.email).set( {Location: [
  {
    X: '45',
    Y: '55',
    time_start: 'Time start',
    time_end: 'Time end'
  }
]
});
```

It gives the following .

[image]

I was wondering if it is possible to have the location and time data under the email field. Something like as follows in data base. For example, **if the user already exists** , then data is to be written under **the same node.**

```
Node --
            | -MDsbPkFKYN3b2uiPt1F: test@gmail.com
                                                               | Location x,y
                                                               | time start , time end
```

Eventually i want to send live location and time stamp based on event .

Is this the best way to do it ? In python , to log in values in json,  one commonly uses , `json.append( )`  to log values and prevent it getting over written.  Tips are welcome

Comment: What you're showing in that last snippet is not valid JSON, which means it can't be stored in Firebase Realtime Database. Please edit your question to show a valid JSON structure that you'd like to store.

Comment: Hi Frank the last snippet is what i was looking in the real time data base , not for desired json file.  If json cannot be stored in realtime database , then i am looking for something similar to the last snippet.

Comment: That last snippet is **not** valid JSON, and I'm having a hard time understanding its structure. Hence the request to replace it by actual valid JSON.